# Video runs for a few frames then gives error

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm working on raspberry pi3 model b+
I installed opencv 3.4.4 on my raspberry pi , and it installed fine. I'm just running a basic code to see my camera output . (i have plugged in two cameras)

Here is the code .

```
import cv2
import time


def show_webcam(mirror=False):
    frame_rate = 30
    prev = 0
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    ff= 0.5

    fxx = ff
    fyy = ff 
    while True:
        ret_val, img = cam.read()
        img2 = cam1.read()[1]
        time_elapsed = time.time() - prev
       # print('data type of frame', type(img))
        if time_elapsed > 1/frame_rate:
            prev = time.time()
            cv2.rectangle(img,(100,100),(500,500),(255,255,0),2)
            small_frame = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=fxx, fy=fyy)
            cv2.resize(img2,(0, 0), fx = fxx, fy = fyy)
            #print("helo")
        #if mirror: 
        #    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
            cv2.imshow('my webcam', img)
            cv2.imshow('my 2nd webcam', img2)
        #if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
        #    break  # esc to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print (cam)

def main():
    show_webcam(mirror=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The videos appear for a few frames but after a few seconds i get this error

```
select timeout
VIDIOC_DQBUF: Resource temporarily unavailable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "camera.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "camera.py", line 36, in main
    show_webcam(mirror=True)
  File "camera.py", line 21, in show_webcam
    small_frame = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=fxx, fy=fyy)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.4) /home/pi/packaging/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3784: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

This same code works fine when i implement it on my laptop. What can i do to correct this error and ensure the video is not interrupted ?

have tried doing cv2.waitKey(30) doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you are using a time_elapsed variable while you can just use the waitkey function and pass to it the milli-sec you want to wait, 1000/framePerSecond. and about your error, the frame you try to resize is empty, sometimes that happens. so before you do any image processing try to check if image image not empty then proceed what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Same code works on laptop but not on pi. This means you have issues to lesser memory and / or cpu on a smaller device.

Try reducing the framerate to adjust how many frames you can work with a smaller device.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the ret_val of both `cam.read()` is true simultaneously before continuing processing. So when a frame is not properly grabbed, it is dropped and the process is retried instead of throwing an error and exiting.

This does not technically resolve the error, but it does solve your problem, provided the resulting framerate is sufficient for your application.